# How to modify dictonaries in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

How can I modify a list value inside dataframes? I am trying to adjust data received by JSON and the DataFrame is as below:

```
Dataframe df:
    id    options
0    0     [{'a':1 ,'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}]
1    1     [{'a':5 ,'b':6, 'c':7, 'd':8}] 
2    2     [{'a':9 ,'b':10, 'c':11, 'd':12}]
```

If I want to use only 'a' and 'c' key / values in options how can I modify datafames? The expected result would be:

```
Dataframe df:
    id    options
0    0     [{'a':1 ,'c':3}]
1    1     [{'a':5 ,'c':7}] 
2    2     [{'a':9 ,'c':11}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just `apply` a function that modifies the entries:

```
>>> df.options = df.options.apply(lambda x: [{k: v for k, v in x[0].items() if k in ('a', 'c')}])
>>> df
   id              options
0   0   [{'a': 1, 'c': 3}]
1   1   [{'a': 5, 'c': 7}]
2   2  [{'a': 9, 'c': 11}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using list comprehension to create new dictionaries with only certain keys:

```
df['options'] = [[{'a': x[0]['a'], 'c': x[0]['c']}] for x in df['options']]
```